# STL sort by variable and then in ascending order

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

How could I sort alphabetically and then by `int` variable in the class? How can I combine them, so if `counter` is the same, it will return in alphabetical order?

```
// sort pages by its popularity

bool popularity(const Page &a, const Page &b) {
 return a.counter > b.counter;
}

// alphabetical sort

bool alphaSort(const Page &a, const Page &b) {
    return a.name < b.name;
}
// Combination?
sort(.begin(), .end(), ??)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to sort the pages by popularity and that you would then like to sort the pages of equal popularity alphabetically?

Comment: yes, exactly what I want to achieve. Both functions works, just not sure how to combine them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend your two criteria to a [lexicographic comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order):

```
bool combinedSort(const Page &a, const Page &b)
{
    return a.counter > b.counter || (a.counter == b.counter && a.name < b.name);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do it with a sort followed by a stable sort.

Comment: The condition may be rewritten as `return std::tie(b.counter, a.name) < std::tie(a.counter, b.name);`

Comment: @Tim Seguine: this could work somehow, but you can't just pass `alphaSort` to the stable sort routine. It would rearrange your previous order (unless by incident the partitions generated by the two criteria match).

Comment: @Jarod42: thanks for the comment, this is indeed a little bit nicer -- once you are willing to take one extra indirection to the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Comment: @davidhigh no no, you `alphaSort` first then stable sort with `popularity`. Stable sort won't change the relative ordering of items with the same popularity, meaning they are still alphabetically sorted.

Comment: @Tim Seguine: yes, that makes more sense.

Comment: @davidhigh If I had stated it more clearly the first time, I wouldn't have had to explain myself again. :)

Comment: @Tim Seguine: right, but actually I'm also a great fan of thinking by oneself ... which I obviously didn't do :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the above combined Sort function (Modified the sort as you want alphabetical first and the int value later.), you can call sort something like this:

Assuming you had a vector of pages

```
bool combinedSort(const Page &a, const Page &b)
{
    return a.name < b.name || (a.name == b.name && a.counter < b.counter);
}

std::vector<Page> pages;
std::sort(pages.begin(), pages.end(), combinedSort);
```

Comment: Note that `a.name < b.name` is not what the OP was asking for in his question -- although given his accept it seems to be what he wanted.